# Getting selected row values in table using jquery in mvc 4 asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I had using jquery to develoing table and i need to get particular row value using click event example shown in below:

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#UsertTypeName').change(function () {

        $.get('/Home/Userdetails/' + $('#UsertTypeName').val(), function (data) {

            var items = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email_id</th><th>UserType</th><th colspan='2'>Actions</th></tr>";

            $.each(data, function (i, count) {

                items += "<tr><td >" + count.FirstName + "</td><td class="+'test'+">" + count.EmailId + "</td><td>" + count.UsertTypeName + "</td><td>" + '<input type="Submit" value="Edit" class="editdata" />' + "</td><td>" +'<input type="submit" Value="Delete" id="deldata">' + "</td></tr>";
            });

            $('#rdata').html(items);
            items += "</table>";

            $('.editdata').click(function () {
                alert("edit working");
                var url = "/Home/Edit/";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: url,
                    data: $('.test').val(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#testing').html(data)
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    });

});
```

I tried to get Email value using .$ajax but it returns only null value

[image]

I could not able to find where i get miss the value.. Can you help me. Advance in thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `count.EmailId` value, which it sounds like you want, when someone clicks on the `<input type="Submit" value="Edit" class="editdata" />` in the same row, then you can use jQuery to find the parent `<tr>` and then find the `<td>` containing the data without referencing the class `.test`, which will return an array. something like this:

```
var emailId = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

This locates the second `<td>` in the same row as the `input` your user clicks, and stores the text within the column as `emailId`:

```
            $('.editdata').click(function () {
            alert("edit working");
            var emailId = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
            var url = "/Home/Edit/";
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: emailId,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#testing').html(data)
                }
            });
```

There is a design issues in your code that I'd like to point out too. Anticipating that your table will have more than one row in its body, `<input type="submit" Value="Delete" id="deldata">` will result in multiple elements with `deldata` as their ID, which will cause some headaches when you're trying to attach event handlers to the ID because the ID field should be unique.